# Laravel where like not working. LIKE % % not working proper

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel project search is not working properly.

Example: If I am trying to search with number `5` it's working fine but if searching like `55` or any more than `2` digit number it converting in non readable format something like `D%` or `S%` or `>%`.

```
->where('sale_property.property_ref_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
```

Comment: Share your code!

Comment: Can you display some code..

Comment: Updated with where clause.

Comment: use `like` instead of `LIKE`

Comment: What is being converted?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
   ->where('sale_property.property_ref_id', 'LIKE', DB::raw("'%$search%'"));
```

Which will keep your dynamic generated string as it is without converting it through query builder or eloquent if you are using.

Do not forget to add namespace above that class.

```
use DB;
```

Comment: Is it the same error you are getting, can you show what is the value of $search?

Comment: It converts the query like       sale_property.property_ref_id` LIKE  "U%".

Answer (score 0):

may be this will work

```
->where('sale_property.property_ref_id', 'LIKE', DB::raw("CONCAT('%', $search, '%')"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simply way :

```
$query = DB::table('YOUR_TABLE_NAME');
$query->where('sale_property.property_ref_id', 'like', '%' . $search. '%');
$query->get();
```

Don't forget to add this namespace :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```